# Decoding repeated Submessage in nanopb

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, nanopb

I've looked through a number of other posts but none seem to resolve my issue.

I'm using `nanoPB` in C, creating messages in json and converting them to `pb` to send to my device.

Given this proto message and options file

```
message PB_BoundingArray {
    enum Shape {
        INVALID = 0;
        CIRCLE = 1;
        UNUSED = 2;
        TRIANGLE = 3;
        QUADRANGLE = 4;
    }
    Shape type = 1;
    repeated float point_x = 2;
    repeated float point_y = 3;
}

message PB_ConfigurationData {
    uint32 min = 1;
    uint32 max = 2;
    PB_BoundingArray bounds = 3;
}
```

```
PB_BoundingArray.point_x max_count:4
PB_BoundingArray.point_x fixed_count:true
PB_BoundingArray.point_y max_count:4
PB_BoundingArray.point_y fixed_count:true
PB_ConfigurationData.bounds max_count:10
PB_ConfigurationData.bounds fixed_count:true
```

I'll create a json file that looks like this:

```
{
    "bounds":
    [
        {
            "point_x":
            [
                39.845129,
                39.840504,
                39.840420,
                39.845119
            ],
            "point_y":
            [
                -102.126389,
                -102.126111,
                -102.118611,
                -102.118611
            ],
            "type": "QUADRANGLE"
        }
    ],
    "max": 90000,
    "min": 10800
}
```

And use a python script and serialize it into protobuf (truncated for berevity)

```
from lib.length_delimited_protobuf import serialize, deserialize
...
elif args.json_file:
    with open(args.json_file, "r") as input_file:
        message = Parse(input_file.read(), message_type)
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(serialize(message))
...
```

The standard output is redirected to a file so it's saved. If I give that file to my `C` function

```
// where buffer is char buffer from a raw read of the .pb file
pb_istream_t stream = pb_istream_from_buffer(buffer, bytesRead);
if(!pb_decode_delimited(&stream, PB_ConfigurationData_fields, &current))
{
    // error handling
}
```

The `pb_decode_delimited` call fails if `bounds` is populated in the `.pb` file with the error message `parent stream too short`.

I don't fully understand why there is not enough data in the stream. I believe the message to be encoded correctly as I can deserialize it in python. My suspicion is there is a flag or some option that needs to be set so I can properly have a repeated sub message with repeated fields within.

Comment: Try verifying the value of `bytesRead` and contents of the `buffer` on the C side. Then you can use e.g. https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode to check if it valid. If you are using Windows the PC, also verify that the streams are set to binary mode.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you transfer the data from python to your embedded target?

Comment: @jpa I can output the buffer but when I press decode on the site you linked, nothing happens. I'm not sure if there's an error decoding it or not since there's no output.

Comment: @Bart Right now I'm doing unit tests, so I'm passing in a local .pb file.

Comment: On what platform are you running unit tests? You can also include hex dump of the data in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue. I was unaware of a max buffer size set elsewhere in the code base that was limiting the buffer size to 64 and some of my messages were 117+ characters long. Therefore they couldn't be decoded.